# simple error: point array

Tags: arrays, visual-c++, point

I have the following:

```
array<Point>^ ADC1=gcnew array<Point>(2);
ADC1={Point(period,points[0][0]),Point(period,points[0][1])}; // error here!
```

However I get the following error when I attempt to compile the code:

error C2059: syntax error : '{'

The error is at the line ADC1={ ...

period is an int and points is a 2D array with int values.

can anyone help me out?

Thanks in advance

Comment: That was stupid! I used ADC1[0] and ADC1[1] and it worked. However, I would still like to know why the above doesn't work.

Comment: If I am right you can make initial value list only at constructor, not after constructing array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can explicit initial values only at constructor level, try:

```
array<Point>^ ADC1=gcnew array<Point>(2);
ADC1[0] = Point(period,points[0][0]);
ACD1[1] = Point(period,points[0][1]);
```

Comment: yea I figured that out. check my previous comment :) . Thanks

Comment: You have posted comment while I was writing this answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Like in regular C++, C++ COM Extensions only allow you to do initialize with an aggregate when constructing, you can't assign an aggregate to an existing array. Something like this should work, though:

```
array<Point>^ ADC1 = gcnew array<Point>{Point(period,points[0][0]),Point(period,points[0][1])};
```

for more info, see the second example on this page: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dtbydz1t.aspx